# Origin of identity: $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \exp\{ - \pi x^2 - 2 \pi^{1/2} a x\} \,da = \exp\left\{a^2\right\}$

Tags: reference-request, math-history, gaussian-integral

A 1959 paper written by J. Hubbard called "Calculation of Partition Functions" and published in Physical Review Letters contains the following identity (Equation 2):

$$\int\limits_{-\infty}^{\infty} \exp\{ - \pi x^2 - 2 \pi^{1/2} a x\} \,da = \exp\left\{a^2\right\}$$

Which can also be written as:

$$\frac{1}{\sqrt{\pi}} \int\limits_{-\infty}^{\infty} \exp\left\{2ax-x^2\right\} \,da = \exp\left\{a^2\right\}$$

I am curious if anyone knows what the exact origin of this identity is, e.g., when was it first published and by whom? Hubbard does not provide any reference in his paper.

Thanks alot!!

Comment: Such a question belongs on hsm.se.

Comment: Take $x \to x + a$ (or $x \to \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}x + a$, depending on your normalization) to reduce it to the standard Gaussian.

Comment: It says in [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaussian_integral) that "Abraham de Moivre originally discovered this type of integral in 1733, while Gauss published the precise integral in 1809."